# Multiple videos on slider playing at specific mouse movements

Tags: javascript, html, css, video, slider

I am looking for a slider exactly as goo.gl/o1GWFr

If you notice, there are multiple videos being played. However, theres specific mouse movements which are being tracked & accordingly only the next video is played when our mouse movement reaches a specific position. Likewise, the same loop continues for more videos in the same slider.

Can anyone guide me as to how was this done? Is there a library or tutorial available to execute the same slider?

I tried inspecting & checking the codes, however am still not able to understand how exactly has it been executed.

Thanks so much in advance, hope to receive amazing support!

Answer (score 0):

[Here's a fiddle I made](https://jsfiddle.net/k31rkggf/).  It achieves a similar (basic) effect, you can use it as a base to build from, however what you're asking for is quite a large amount of work. Do some research, look at delaying certain videos playing, counting how many iteration of the animation have run, then using that information to determine which video plays.

So how my example works: The jQuery initiates a CSS animation and plays the videos, when you hover over a transparent div on the right-hand side of the slider.  When you take your mouse off that div, it pauses the CSS animation and pauses one of the videos, but leaves one playing.

The Code:
HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="hoverPanel"></div>
  <div id="b">
    <img src="http://vtdavy.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/life_in_space.jpg">
    <img src="http://www.thespaceshow.com/sites/default/files/shows/styles/front_page_three_blocks/public/Deep-Space-Cloud3_0.jpg?itok=QBRCnvLL">
    <img src="http://vtdavy.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/life_in_space.jpg">
    <img src="http://www.thespaceshow.com/sites/default/files/shows/styles/front_page_three_blocks/public/Deep-Space-Cloud3_0.jpg?itok=QBRCnvLL">
    <video muted loop id="v1" class="vidz" width="100px" height="auto">
      <source src="http://mazwai.com/system/posts/videos/000/000/208/original/white-lilies.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
    <video muted loop id="v2" class="vidz" width="100px" height="auto">
      <source src="http://mazwai.com/system/posts/videos/000/000/208/original/white-lilies.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div.wrapper {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 800px;
  height: 210px;
  position: relative;
}
#b {
  position:relative;
  width: 1600px; // Width of four images
}
.run {
  animation: moveSlideshow 12s linear infinite;
}
#b > img {
  float: left;
  width: 400px;
}
@keyframes moveSlideshow {
  100% { 
    transform: translateX(-800px);  
  }
}
.vidz{ 
  position: absolute;
}
#v1 {
  bottom: 0;
  left: 500px;
}
#v2 {
  top: 0;
  left: 850px;
}
.hoverPanel {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 2;
}
.clearfix {
  clear: both;
}
```

jQuery:

```
var vid = document.getElementById("v1"); 
var vid2 = document.getElementById("v2"); 

function playVid() { 
    vid.play(); //plays #v1
    vid2.play(); //plays #v2
} 

function pauseVid() { 
    vid.pause(); 
}
$(".hoverPanel").on("mouseover", function(){
  playVid(); // run playVid function
  if ($("#b").hasClass("run")){
  $(".run").css({"-webkit-animation-play-state": "running", "animation-play-state": "running"}); //plays slider
  }
  else {
  $("#b").addClass("run"); //Adds animation class
  }
});
$(".hoverPanel").on("mouseleave", function(){
    $(".run").css({"-webkit-animation-play-state": "paused", "animation-play-state": "paused"}); //pauses slider
  pauseVid(); // run pauseVid function
});
```